# Outputting array to listbox control using loops (visual basic)

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, loops, listbox

I am new to Visual Basic and have a homework assignment as follows:

"You are to create an array of 10 elements, String type, and load 10 unique values into the array, one value per element. Your program must then output those values into a Listbox control.

Note: Your program MUST use a loop to load the data into the array(Hint: use InputBox function), and another loop to output it to the Listbox control. How your program acquires the information is up to you, but processing must be done using loops."

I am confused about how to enter the data that I want (arrayvalue(0) - arrayvalue(9)) via loop to a listbox.

I started with:

```
    Dim n as integer = 10
    Dim fruitarray(n) as string
    Do Until fruitarray(n)=10
    fruitarray(0) = "watermelon"
        fruitarray(1) = "apple"
        fruitarray(2) = "pear"
        fruitarray(3) = "plum"
        fruitarray(4) = "pineapple"
        fruitarray(5) = "grapes"
        fruitarray(6) = "strawberry"
        fruitarray(7) = "raspberry"
        fruitarray(8) = "banana"
        fruitarray(9) = "blackberry"
        ListBox1.Items.Add(CStr(n))
    Loop
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*You are doing all the things in one loop and without using InputBox as per requirement.
so here is your solution.*

```
    int n = 10;
    string[] fruitarray = new string[n]

    Dim message, title As String 
    message = "Enter your value" 
    title = "InputBox Demo"


    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        fruitarray[i]=InputBox(message, title, defaultValue)        
     }


   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
      ListBox1.Items.Add(fruitarray[i]);
   }
```